# s y c en "inconsciente"

Tags: ortografía

Sé que la palabra "**inconsciente**" está bien escrita con la combinación "**sc**" (gracias al corrector ortográfico de LibreOffice).

Pero también sé que la palabra principal de la familia es "**conciencia**", sin la "s".

¿Hay alguna regla al respecto?, ¿existe la "consciencia"?

Comment: Existe [consciencia](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=consciencia)

Comment: _¿existe la "consciencia"?_ qué profundo se ha vuelto este stack exchange

Comment: @clinch, somos _conscientes_ de ello!! ;-)

Comment: Quizás no seas consciente de que esta duda te la resuelve el diccionario.

Comment: Creo que no hay ninguna regla al respecto. He tratado de encontrar algo al respecto buscando la etimología de la palabra, pero sin suerte.

Comment: OK, gracias a todos por su tiempo. Saco en limpio de lo dicho por AmparadoLento y Lucas que normalmente _conciencia_ y _consciencia_ son lo mismo. Parece haber una diferencia entre el **estado mental** y el **sentido moral**, pero AmparadoLento y Lucas los usan al revés, por lo que no se puede sacar ninguna conclusión. Lo mejor, entonces, es escribir _consciente_ e _inconsciente_ siempre con _sc_, como nos dice @Lucas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the meanings of *conciencia* and *consciencia* are the same. Nevertheless, they come from the same latin word:

From RAE:

**conciencia.**

(Del lat. conscientĭa, y este calco del gr. συνείδησις).

1. f. Propiedad del espíritu humano de reconocerse en sus atributos esenciales y en todas las modificaciones que en sí mismo experimenta.
2. f. Conocimiento interior del bien y del mal.
3. f. Conocimiento reflexivo de las cosas.
4. f. Actividad mental a la que solo puede tener acceso el propio sujeto.
5. f. Psicol. Acto psíquico por el que un sujeto se percibe a sí mismo en el mundo.

**consciencia.**

(Del lat. conscientĭa).

1. f. conciencia.
2. f. Conocimiento inmediato que el sujeto tiene de sí mismo, de sus actos y reflexiones.
3. f. Capacidad de los seres humanos de verse y reconocerse a sí mismos y de juzgar sobre esa visión y reconocimiento.

As a native speaker, I will use more often *conciencia* for any of its meanings (especially when talking about the knowledge of what is good and evil:

```
¡Asesino! ¡No tienes conciencia!
```

And *consciencia* mostly for the exact meaning of knowledge of own existence (for which I disagree with the arcaic and anthropocentric definition that gives as granted that no more animals have self-awareness) and at any place where I could use (with different grammar) the word *consciente*:

```
Soy consciente (tengo consciencia) de tu precaria situación, pero no puedo hacer nada.
```

Please note that *conciente* and *inconciente* do not exist, and the presence or absence of that s is only in the word *con(s)ciencia*.

Answer (score 1):

I found this: http://reglasespanol.about.com/od/palabras-dudosa-ortografia/a/Conciencia-Consciencia-Conciente-Consciente.htm

They are two different words with different meanings. I didn't know and I'm native speaker.

Conciencia significa el sentido moral.

> Le remordía la conciencia

Consciencia significa tener presente la realidad o tener presente un conocimiento.

> Estaba consciente de su situación en la milicia
>
> Recuperó la consciencia después de estar tres meses en estado de coma.

Comment: Puedes mejorar mucho una respuesta poniendo un breve sumario de lo que contiene el link y porqué crees que es representativo. La filosofía detrás de esta forma de hacer las cosas es que si la página web que enlazas desapareciese, tu respuesta se queda "huérfana" y sin contenido. Si pones lo más representativo, aunque desaparezca el enlace, el contenido importante para responder la pregunta sigue estando en este sitio.